# replacing one character with another when not next to a certain other character

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I know how to do this in code with loops and if statements, but im not sure how to do this in tsql.

Note, when I say CR and LF i mean char(13) and char(10)

basically i want to find everything with a CR and replace it with a CRLF.
Hoever, It is slightly more complicated than this because if I ever hit a CRLF, I dont want the result to be CRCRLF.
I want to replace all instances in a column, not just the first occurrence. Any idea on the tsql way of doing this would be great.

One horrible hack would be to go through the and replace any CR with CRLF resulting in some CRCRLF and then run a second update to replace any CRCRLF with CRLF but that can't be the best way could it?

Comment: the whole thing would be nice just to make sure im syntatically correct, but I can probably make my own update.  I'm not following your suggested post though

Comment: What is so terrible about two passes?

Comment: You swapped cr and lf. lf is chr(10) and cr is chr(13)

Comment: @adam kim: if you can use SQLCLR you could use regular expressions with a negative lookbehind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, one method would be to replace the current instances of CRLF with CR and then do the replacement:

```
with chars as (
      select char(10) as lf, char(13) as cr
     )
update t
    set col = replace(replace(col, cr + lf, cr), cr, cr + lf)
    from t cross join
         chars;
```

Comment: This would leave a lone lf unmodified  I would replace(replace(replace(col,crlf,lf),cr,lf),lf,crlf)

Comment: @hetOrakel . . . That is a reasonable suggestion.  The question, however, explicitly says:  "basically i want to find everything with a CR and replace it with a CRLF".

Comment: . . You are right, but... 1) he swapped cr and lf (see my comment there) and 2) he expects a single CR. I do not know of any recent OS that uses a single CR. Today it is CRLF (x0Dx0A / 13+10) or LF (x0A / 10). Even apple (OSX) is using LF (x0A / 10) nowadays. So i doubt what he asks is what he really wants ;). But there's only one person who can answer that ;)

Comment: @GordonLinoff
I was migrating from a foxpro database so there were lots of CR that I had to replace.  
2 other things:...
1. could you please edit your answer to set char(13) as cr and char(10) as Lf? I obviously overlooked the ancii correct code when I wrote my question; I dont want someone to be misled...

2. why did this syntax below result in no change, but your syntax worked? update table1 set column1 = replace(column1, char(13), char(13)+char(10))